# Install and use a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I am brand new to using React and am trying to figure out how to install a component from GitHub and use it in my project.

I started a new app by `npx create-react-app`

The component I want to use is [react-email-editor](https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor) I have followed the documentation as closely as possible but I'm running into errors.

**The error says**

> Failed to compile ./node_modules/react-email-editor/es/index.js Module
>   not found: Can't resolve 'styled-components' in
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Programing\Javascript\emailbuilder\node_modules\react-email-editor\es'

**Code in App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import EmailEditor from 'react-email-editor'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <EmailEditor
        ref={editor => this.editor = editor}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node modules and run `npm install`.  If that doesn't work, then that component might be broken.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: Im running 16.4.1

Comment: It looks like in their GitHub issues, they might be having problems with React 16

Comment: I got it! I saw them saying that. Once I installed that locally with `npm install --save styled-components` it now loads just fine!

Comment: Thats great! Glad I could help